# make image go on top of nav bar

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem trying to make images go over specific areas on my nav bar or in general having a hard time making them go on top of the links.

*code has been deleted as website is posted*

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: put your `style` between `<head></head>` tag or in a separate css file

Comment: ok will do gimme a sec!

Comment: @aldanux style is now in head

Comment: @aldanux I think you got confused I want it like this: http://imgur.com/gjcSLdq

Comment: There are some tags with double class attribute, but I don't see any problem with adding an image on top of home. Do you mind to publish what you have on fiddle?

Comment: Sure! @derloopkat Beware I have not added the place holders

Comment: I guess Aldanux mean that all your code including html is in your head section, because there is a slash missing in your close head tag. Also <div id="links"> and <nav class="navbar-inner"> are unclosed. These things may or may not have to do with the issue.

Comment: @derloopkat here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/7faLnztj/ if you would like me to upload the images with it. I will

Comment: @derloopkat  I got it I found a way around! Thanks for helping.

Comment: @aldanux t I got it I found a way around! Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around!

```
<div class="homeimg"> <img src="img/staff.png" alt="logo2" width="64" height="64"> <style> div.homeimg { top: 500px; left: 0px; right: 205px; bottom: 0px; position: fixed; } </style> </div>
```

---

This is the easist way I found!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you put the style tag inside a div tag.. styling should go in `<head><style>...</style></head>` or `<head><link /></head>`